# Replace values based on numerical criteria only for selected columns, R

Tags: r, replace, assign

My data frame contains plots in rows and corresponding informations in columns (elevation, inclination, covers for different plant species) e.g.

```
nr<- 1:4
elev<- c(1000,1100,1200,1300 )
inclination<-c(10,11,12,13)
spec1<-c( 10,20,40,10)
spec2<-c(0.1, 0.2, 0.9, "")
spec3<-c(33,22,11,1)

releves<- data.frame(nr, elev, inclination, spec1, spec2, spec3)
```

Plant covers should be assigned to a self-defined multi-level scale e.g:

- 1111: covers <= 1
- 2222: > 1 covers<= 10
- 3333: > 10 covers<= 20

The difficulty is that I want to make this assignment **only for columns that contain the covers**.

When I reassign with **<-** , all  numeric values in the data frame change. e.g.

```
releves[releves<=1]<- 1111
releves[releves >1 & releves <=10] <- 2222
releves[releves >10 & releves <=20] <- 3333
releves
```

But this should not happen, because number, elevation or inclination must remain the same. Then I tried with replace() function, but got an error message.

```
replace(releves, releves[ , 4:6 ] >1 & releves[ , 4:6 ] <=10, 2222)
```

How can I apply this assignment to selected columns?
Thanks for your advice!!!

Comment: What does your expected output table look like after the reassignments?

Comment: Is there a reason that `spec2` is character while the others are numeric? It's inconsistent and likely a mistake in processing (caused by your use of `""` here instead of `NA`, perhaps).

Comment: No, actually spec2 should also be numeric. With NA instead of " " this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Up front, I'm correcting for the fact that `spec2` is string here while the others are numeric. If you truly intend to have different and/or non-numeric classes, we may need to revisit this.

```r
releves$spec2 <- as.numeric(releves$spec2)
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
releves %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("spec"),
    ~ case_when(
        . <= 1 ~ 1111, 
        . <= 10 ~ 2222, 
        . <= 20 ~ 3333, 
        TRUE ~ .)
  ))
#   nr elev inclination spec1 spec2 spec3
# 1  1 1000          10  2222  1111    33
# 2  2 1100          11  3333  1111    22
# 3  3 1200          12    40  1111  3333
# 4  4 1300          13  2222    NA  1111
```

This relies on the premise that in `case_when`, the first-found condition is used and the rest are ignored. Because of that, when we evaluate `. <= 10` we don't need to wonder if the number was really `<= 1`.

### base R

We don't have `case_when` in base, we can craft another method using `findInterval` instead.

```r
releves[, grep("^spec", names(releves))] <- 
  lapply(releves[, grep("^spec", names(releves))], function(z) {
    ind <- findInterval(z, c(-Inf, 1, 10, 20), left.open = TRUE)
    ifelse(is.na(ind), z, c(1111, 2222, 3333)[ind])
  })
releves
#   nr elev inclination spec1 spec2 spec3
# 1  1 1000          10  2222  1111    NA
# 2  2 1100          11  3333  1111    NA
# 3  3 1200          12    NA  1111  3333
# 4  4 1300          13  2222    NA  1111
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, both of your suggestions work.  The problem is that my real dataset has correct species names. e.g. Sunflower, Tulip, Rose (instead of spec1, spec2, spec3). Is there a solution where I select the columns by position or by name?

Comment: `releves[,4:6] <- lapply(releves[,4:6], ...)` works for base, and `across(c(Sunflower, Tulip, Rose), ~ ...)` for dplyr works as well.